# Generate viewcontrollers for every day of the year

Tags: ios, swift

So the point is that I would like to have a viewcontroller for every day of the year in my custom navigation bar menu. I am using PagingMenuController library as my menu. There does not have to be 365 menu tabs, the interval can be like 90 days and every time the day changes it deletes the first day from the array and creates new one as last day of the array.

Basically is there a way to achieve it any way painlessly?

The app called ClutchPoints has this feature and I would like to get the exact same result.

This might be too much but I really hope there are some generous people out there who can help me.

Comment: 365 view controllers aren't happy at all :)). You should only have a few or just one, with reusable views on them. But that's up to you!

Comment: Yes, @Xcoder123 is correct. 365 *UIVIews* is poorly coded enough. 365 *UIViewControllers*? You're probably over that magical 100 MB limit with totally blank views. Please, rethink your app design.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create 365 (or even 90) views at a time. You will have serious memory/performance problems if you do that.

You should look at the way table views, collection views, and UIPageViewControllers work. Those all only create the small number of views/view controllers that are actually visible at any one time, and configure the visible ones based on a data source that has the array of data that is being displayed. The views are recycled in order to manage memory.